# CSS rendering issue with triangle down on header image

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to apply a triangle down at the bottom of my image but I'm experiencing an issue. What is the problem?

Looks good on jsfiddle: [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Smzmn/148/)

Doesn't look good on my live page (border is only applied to the right side of the image): [here](https://divi.be-pixel.net/divi-test/)

Looks good (fiddle):
[image]

Doesn't look good:
[image]

```
.header-triangle-down:before, .header-triangle-down:after {
    box-sizing: border-box !important;
    content: " ";
    position: absolute !important;
    top:0 !important;
    display: block !important;
    width: 50% !important;
    height: 100% !important;
    border-bottom: 30px solid red !important;
}

.header-triangle-down:before {
    left: 0;
    border-right: 20px solid transparent !important;
    border-left: 0;
}

.header-triangle-down:after {
    right: 0;
    border-left: 20px solid transparent !important;
    border-right: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is displaying correctly on your live site as well, but overlapped by other elements. Try adding a z-index on your before element, like this:

```
.header-triangle-down:before {
  left: 0;
  border-right: 20px solid transparent !important;
  border-left: 0;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
.header-triangle-down:before {
    left: 0;
    border-right: 20px solid transparent !important;
    border-left: 0;
    z-index: 1;
}
```